# Firebase analytics : not able to add google service plugin in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-analytics

I have following at project level :

classpath `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'`

Works well i have Android Studio 2.1.2

As per project requirement I need to add `firebase` `anaylytics` to my project.

```
buildscript {
// ...
dependencies {
    // ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

}

and

apply plugin: `'com.google.gms.google-services'`

while adding all above requirements it gives error as follow

> Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.

I am stuck with this problem kindly guide if someone has this issue before

moudle level gradle

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.videoapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please post your gradle files.

Comment: Module level gradle file and please post in your question edit it

Comment: done please have a look at it

Comment: Please try this Go to File-> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart